# Google Geocoding API and Google Maps showing different locations

Tags: python, json, google-maps, google-geocoder

I have an excel sheet with address and I want the corresponding latitude longitude data for them.
I am using Python Code to access the Google Geocoding API. The resultant json data shows the formatted address to be an absolutely different place.

**Here is an example of a resultant url output from my code.**

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Phoenix+Market+City+LBS+Road,+Kurla+West,+Mumbai+-+400070+Maharashtra,+India&key=AIzaSyDIVQBLxNxHI2LeUMELHeV3ryl-M6

The resultant json output shows this to be in a completely different locality. But when I directly paste the address -

```
*"Phoenix Market City
LBS Road,
Kurla (West),
Mumbai - 400070
Maharashtra, India"*
```

into the Google maps interface, it finds the exact place I am searching for(I have modified the API key in the URL above to avoid misuse)

Is there is a problem with the API or with the way I am formatting the address string?

Comment: That is not an address, "Phoenix Market City" is a "place".  You will probably find better coordinates using the places API.

Comment: I'm getting "location: {
lat: 19.0855218,
lng: 72.8889313
}" from API. Looks good to me. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:red%7Clabel:S%7C19.0855218,72.8889313&center=19.0855218,72.8889313&zoom=17&size=600x600

Comment: Checked Places API. It is better suited. P - Places API result, G - Geocoding API result. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:red%7Clabel:G%7C19.0855218,72.8889313&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:P%7C19.086486,72.88875&center=19.0855218,72.8889313&zoom=17&size=600x600

Comment: @geocodezip - I read up on the places API and it does seem better suited. I have gone though my list in further detail and I see that it is a mix of Places and Addresses. Can you suggest a strategy by which my code can differentiate between the 2?

**Sangharsh** - You are right, the example above was probably not the worst of the lost in all of the 10 addresses I checked manually. Of these 1 was going to a wildly different place and the other 2 were misleading (I assumed they were inaccurate by looking at the "formatted address" field on the returned json stream)